# How to show admbob ad to another activity in my android app

Tags: android, admob

I create an android app, Now i want to add admob ad but My admob ad show main activity but do not show other activity,now what i can  do?

Comment: Do same, you did in your mainActivity, Means add AdView code in layout and write its java code in it's class file.

Comment: yes i add AdView code in layout and write its java code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AdView to the layout of your other activities and setup him from the Activity's java code.